# WF4 Workflow persistence store: Is the XAML definition stored along with the instance data?

Tags: xaml, versioning, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

Environment: Workflow Foundation 4, SQL persistence  store.
Requirement: I have a bookmark which has to be resumed with the same XAML which was used to initialize the instance.

I vaguely remember reading about it a while back somewhere, but I am not sure anymore. Is the XAML definition stored along with the instance data in the persistence store? Or is it our responsibility to maintain multiple XAML versions as part of deployment? This is in the context of workflow version maintenance. My line of thought: assuming the Activity binaries remain the same, it might probably be easier to resume a persisted workflow if the XAML definition is also available in the persistence database! One manual workaround: store the version number of the XAML file in the database and the corresponding versioned XAML file in the deployment folder.

Any other alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the XAML contents are not stored along with the workflow state and you have to take care of that.